# collection_select with nestled resources

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So, my first question on Stackoverflow!
Lets see how it goes...

So I've got a `collection_select` who represents the current category you are on:

```
<%= collection_select(:category, :slug, current_user.categories, :slug, :name) %>
```

This select represents which category the user currently is on, and the user should be able to switch between the categories.

The categories have post like so:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :posts
end
```

I want the `collection_select` to automatically select the current category based on url parameters, which works so far:

```
http://myproject.com/categories/action
```

The selected value is the same as the current url parameter.
But it does not work when the user navigates to a post :

```
http://myproject.com/categories/action/my-new-post
```

This resets the `collection_select`, I figured it has something to do with nestled resources, what should i do?

Just to clarify: i have a very simple javascript to reload the page when user selects a category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set an initial value for your collection select. Something like:

```
<%= collection_select(:category, :slug, current_user.categories, :slug, :name {:selected => params[YOUR_PARAM_NAME_HERE]}) %>
```

Alternatively, if you can do something like this

```
<%= collection_select(:category, :slug, current_user.categories, :slug, :name {:selected => @category.slug} %>
```

Is that about right?

Comment: Yes that worked, but only in my second case though: `http://myproject.com/categories/action/my-new-post` My parameter is changing depending on where in my application I am, if I'm in a post `http://myproject.com/categories/action/my-new-post` the parameter is: `category_id`, and if i'm just in a category it is: `id`. If i do not define `:selected => params[:category_id]` it works when i'm in a post, and if i _do_ define it, it does not work when i'm just in a category. And after some reading, shouldn't `collection_select` automatically figure this out?

Comment: Actually found a solution which works: `:selected => lambda { return params[:id] || params[:category_id] }.call` But i really doubt this is the best, or even a good solution. There have to be a cleaner way of doing this.